# When $[G_k,G_m] = G_{k+m}$?

Tags: combinatorial-group-theory, gr.group-theory

Hello?
I have a simple question about combinatorial group theory.

For a group $G$, I saw $[G_k, G_m] \subset G_{k+m}$ and these two subgroups need not be equal.
Then is there any known condition that they can be equal?
How about the case that $G$ is (f.g.) free?

Actually, my first question was that:
for a f.g. free group $F$, $F_m \subset [F_k,F_k]$ for some big $m$?

Comment: Can you say what $G_k$ etc. means?

Comment: Presumably the lower central series

Comment: As $D_\infty$ is metabelian but not nilpotent, it follows that $F_m$ is not contained in $[F_k,F_k]$ for any $k$.

Comment: Sorry for you to confuse. Derek Holt is right.
And what is $D_\infty$?

Comment: @qkqh: I suppose $D_{\infty}$ is the infinite dihedral group $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: $A_4$ is another (finite) example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presumably $G=G_1 \ge G_2 \ge G_3 \ge \cdots$ is the lower central series of $G$?

So, for a free group $F$ of rank $r$, $F_2$ = $[F,F]$, and $F/[F_2,F_2]$ is the free $r$-generator metabelian group.

$F_m < [F_2,F_2]$ would imply that $F/[F_2,F_2]$ is nilpotent of class at most $m$, but since there are 2-generator metabelian groups that are not nilpotent, this is not possible for $r \ge 2$.